# Sqoop job failed with "illegal escape character" error

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, cloudera

I used below command to sqoop data from a Oracle table to a Hive table with the same table structure.

```
sqoop import -Dorg.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter=true -query "select * from schema.oracle_table where \$CONDITIONS"  --split-by "CUSTOMER_REF" -connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:Port:SID --username username --password password --hcatalog-table database.hive_table --hcatalog-database database --input-null-string "\\N" --input-null-non-string "\\N" --verbose --escaped-by "\\" --enclosed-by '\"'
```

It gives below error.

```
/tmp/sqoop-u012454/compile/87a7c921728bc9550a3df3e3fe38e150/QueryResult.java:1165: error: illegal escape character
    if (__cur_str.equals("\N") || __cur_str.length() == 0) { this.DSP = null; } else {
                           ^
64 errors

22/01/09 19:09:33 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: java.io.IOException: Error returned by javac
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager.compile(CompilationManager.java:226)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:515)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:633)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:182)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:233)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:242)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:251)
```

I tried adding `--escaped-by "\\" --enclosed-by '\"'` , but it didn't work.

Comment: What are you expecting `\$CONDITIONS` to be? Sqoop has a flag for where statements, so you shouldn't be using a raw query like this

Comment: after removing --input-null-string "\\N" --input-null-non-string "\\N" options, it successfully got completed